# where to fill tax deduction for legal fee related to "related to doing or keeping your job" in form 529?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, california, employment

I filed for extension in april because i didn't have this information but need to file by Oct 15th.

I paid around 750 dollars last year to consult lawyers regarding a threatening letter from a former employer related to company confidential information where they asked me to sign additional confidentiality agreements and threatened a bit. There was no lawsuit. The lawyer gave me advice, i paid them $750 and that was pretty much the end of it.

**Form 529 says this** and it's a legal expense that was incurred trying to defend against a former employer. BUT it doesn't where/which Line to deduct them.

> You *can* deduct legal expenses that are *related to doing or keeping your job*, such as those you paid to defend yourself against criminal charges arising out of your trade or business.

**Publication 529 page 2 also says:**

> You can no longer claim a deduction for unreimbursed employee expenses *unless you fall into one of the following categories* of employment, or have certain qualified educator expenses. • Armed Forces reservists. • Qualified performing artists. • Fee-basis state or local government officials. • Employees with impairment-related work expenses.

It seems that the only way it can be deducted is through an "above-the-line" subtraction from the gross income (goes into Line7/1040), as adjustments to income into *Line 36 of schedule 1* of 2018 Form 1040.

**But Line 36 of Schedule-1 Form 1040 says:**

> On the dotted line next to line 36, enter the amount of your deduction and identify it as indicated.
>   Attorney fees and court costs for actions involving certain unlawful dis-crimination claims, but only to the ex-tent of gross income from such actions (see Pub. 525). Identify as “UDC.”

So it suggests to put only "unlawful dis-crimination claims" as UDC.

**Based on this the question is:**

- It seems evident that these $750 can be deducted as 529 clearly says "You *can* deduct legal expenses that are *related to doing or keeping your job*". where can one find how to go about deducting it?
- which Line # and Form specifically to deduct it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one deduct lawyer consult fee less than $1000 for ex-employer's threat letter related to confidentiality in 2018 taxes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107890/can-one-deduct-lawyer-consult-fee-less-than-1000-for-ex-employers-threat-lette)